# Halley's method in C or Octave

Tags: function, methods, root, octave

I have been working on a math project recently and I need some help. I got stuck in a point where I need to write a program that represents Halley's method which is something actually similar to Newton's method of approximation algorithm for finding a root of a function.

thats what I have at the moment. Since I dont have much of programming knowledge could you tell me what could be improved to make it work?

I assumed p, q being values of first and second derrivatives of a function.

```
 function y = halley (f, x_0)
 x=x_0 + 10;
 x_new = x_0;
 while ( abs(x_new - x)> 0.00001)
     x = x_new;
     p = (f(x+0.00001) - f(x)) / 0.0001;
     q = (f(x+0.00001) - 2*f(x) + f(x-0.00001)) / (0.0000000001);
     x_new = x-((2* f(x)*p) / (((2*p)^2) -(q*f(x)))
    end;
    y =x_new
 end;
```

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works. If you have a problem understanding the algorithm, or a specific problem with your attempt at trying to write the code, we'll happily help with that, but asking someone to write / find code for you is not appropriate.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a request to have code written, not for help with code that OP is trying to write.